# How to create search bar like uc browser search bar toolbar in android studio Kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, browser, android-toolbar

[It's uc browser toolbar on home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lUtZ.jpg)
[It's screen when user click onsearch bara on home screen then it's expand left end user desire search engine and right end cancel button and mic in between search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzlUe.jpg)
[When user type anything then the button chage mic button change into clear text button and cancel button change into go search button,other are same as before there is no changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLcEH.jpg)
[When user click on google image button then search engine list show and user chose which search engine he want to seach query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIlOz.jpg)
In this hole process only button changes their no change in search bar.
But in my xml file any user clearly see their are three toolbar transmition one to another. Please anyon can tell me what can i do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".fragment.HomeFragment">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/first_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_design"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/google"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/google_image"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/google"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_input"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/mic"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/google"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/search_or_enter_url"
                android:textColor="#494747"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mic"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/mic"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_mic_24"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/second_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/second_toolbar_menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <!-- This is the search bar layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

            <!-- Google Image -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/second_google"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@string/google_image"
                android:src="@drawable/google"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />

            <!-- EditText for input -->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/second_search_input"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:autofillHints="Enter Text or Search Url"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Search or Enter URL"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="#494747"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

            <!-- Mic / Cross Button -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/second_mic"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/cancel_search"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@string/mic"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_mic_24"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

            <!-- Divider divide between mic and textView -->
            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/cancel_search"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/mic"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/black_light"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,UnusedAttribute" />

            <!-- cancel search / search_Or_Go -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cancel_search"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="#434141"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,TextSizeCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/third_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/second_toolbar_menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <!-- This is the search bar layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/third_search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp">

            <!-- Google Image -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/third_google"
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@string/google_image"
                android:src="@drawable/google"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />

            <!-- EditText for input -->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/third_search_input"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:autofillHints="Enter Text or Search Url"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Search or Enter URL"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#494747"
                android:textColorHint="#494747"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />

            <!-- It's clear text in EditText for input -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/clear_text"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black_light"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_cancel_24"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,HardcodedText,ObsoleteLayoutParam,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/second_divider"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/cancel_search"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/search_Or_Go"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/black_light"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,UnusedAttribute" />

            <!-- when user click search_Or_Go button then it will go to search page using webview -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_Or_Go"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,HardcodedText,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want my search bar exact behavior like the uc search bar. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

*Please change icon and used this layout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".activity.NewActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/google"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
    app:tint="@color/black"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/google"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/box_one"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:hint="search here"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/box_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
        app:tint="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0.8dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        app:tint="@color/black"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Rahul Brother Thanks for your response but my whole question is  When the user types anything the button changes mic button change into a clear text button and the cancel button change into a go search button, other are the same as before there is no changes ."I want my search bar behaviour same as UC browser search bar.

Comment: please used this "addTextChangedListener"

Answer (score 0):

*This is java code, please used your side, mic code not available*

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context context;
private EditText edtSearch;
private ImageView imgMic, imgSearch, imgClose, imgGoogle;
private TextView txtCancel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    init();
}
private void init(){
    context = this;
    edtSearch = findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
    imgMic = findViewById(R.id.img_mic);
    imgGoogle = findViewById(R.id.img_google);
    imgSearch = findViewById(R.id.img_search);
    imgClose = findViewById(R.id.img_close);
    txtCancel = findViewById(R.id.txt_cancel);
    imgClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imgMic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imgSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txtCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    setOnClick();
}
private void setOnClick() {
    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgMic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            edtSearch.setText(" ");
            imgSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtCancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (count == 0){
                imgMic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            imgClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgMic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}}
```

*xml code*

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".activity.NewActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_google"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
    app:tint="@color/black"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_google"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/box_one"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:hint="search here"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/box_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_close"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_close"
        app:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_mic"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_mic"
        app:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0.8dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_search"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_search"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        app:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```